# chkdsk starts on every boot and alot of files got corrupted

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, chkdsk

Last week my system hdd (1tb) got bricked so, i replaced it with a new one (2tb), that's not a problem at all, the problem with my data hdd (4tb --> 1 partition), windows do chkdsk on that hdd on every boot, and alot of my important files got corrupted, i also tried to redownload some of these files but when i restarted my pc, it got also corrupted, but it was recoverable with chkdsk command from cmd, here is the log of the last chkdsk process,

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
The attribute list length 0x300 in file 0x1580c is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x0.

Truncating corrupt attribute list for file 88076.
The attribute list in file 0x1580c does not contain
standard information attribute.
Deleted corrupt attribute list for file 88076.
  105984 file records processed.                                          File verification completed.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88196.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88217.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88353.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88427.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88456.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88462.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88468.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88477.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88478.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88480.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88481.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88492.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88495.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88496.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88497.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88498.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88499.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88514.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88515.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88521.
Deleting orphan file record segment 88523.
  3929 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                        0 EA records processed.                                              0 reparse records processed.                                       CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x28c is incorrect.
f5 b5 15 a3 3b b7 5e 5e 32 9d 16 94 66 58 20 7c  ...£;.^^2.fX |
4a 21 e9 ca 36 7b ef b9 6b c0 0b 45 33 cd c7 48  J!é.6{ï.k..E3..H

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 652.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x28c is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 652.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff bc 8c ef 64 d4 00 00 80  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ.ïd....
41 00 47 f6 fe 07 00 00 80 80 27 00 00 00 00 00  A.G.......'.....
Sorting index $I30 in file 652.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2c5 is incorrect.
7e 91 80 af 2d 2c f4 b7 78 0a 40 81 72 8b 9c c7  ~..¯-,..x.@.r.
b2 39 53 94 c6 5d 60 25 02 ee 0b 44 c5 6a 96 f5  .9S.]`%.î.D.j.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 709.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2c5 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 709.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
c0 5c 07 00 00 00 00 00 04 19 7a 64 d4 00 00 80  .\........zd....
Sorting index $I30 in file 709.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2d0 is incorrect.
14 97 8f d7 76 58 44 6c 1d 8b 96 02 61 93 44 5f  ...vXDl..aD_
5a f8 3c f3 f4 1f 98 27 3b 4d 44 bf 57 b0 3c 10  Zø<...';MD.W.<.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 720.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2d0 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 720.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿf.......
6e 02 00 00 00 00 01 00 70 00 5a 00 00 00 00 00  n.......p.Z.....
Sorting index $I30 in file 720.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2d8 is incorrect.
d6 c9 3f a2 b0 e2 be 32 a5 c5 1e 3c 75 0e ab 09  ..?¢.â.2¥..<u.«    
cc 3b a4 d5 ec 2a 6d ef ca 43 51 60 72 d7 75 a3  .;¤.ì*mï.CQ`r.u£
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 728.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2d8 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 728.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
10 00 00 00 28 02 00 00 28 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....(...(.......
Sorting index $I30 in file 728.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2dd is incorrect.
f5 d7 0c 3e 1b f0 0a 87 23 1c 1f 6e 5e 04 cd 7e  ...>...#..n^..~
ae 34 33 61 22 4e 94 96 1f eb ad e7 d4 6b 95 77  ®43a"N.ë­ç.kw
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 733.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2dd is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 733.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Sorting index $I30 in file 733.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2e4 is incorrect.
5d c1 c5 bd ab bf c7 f5 0f f9 c5 b1 47 ce 98 2b  ]...«.......G.+
c2 f2 4e 17 a0 35 6d 27 66 98 36 76 14 f9 d0 f8  ..N. 5m'f6v...ø

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 740.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2e4 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 740.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
10 00 00 00 28 02 00 00 28 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....(...(.......
Sorting index $I30 in file 740.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x2e6 is incorrect.
f3 df b6 3f 81 b6 fd d6 43 0b 74 f0 b5 86 bd eb  ...?..ý.C.t....ë
d2 6c 74 c2 c8 0f fc 05 c0 36 0d da 68 9b 91 7d  .lt...ü..6..h.}
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 742.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x2e6 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 742.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
10 00 00 00 28 02 00 00 28 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....(...(.......
Sorting index $I30 in file 742.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x316 is incorrect.
f2 15 1d d4 87 5e 09 63 9f 18 7c 23 34 7c b8 fb  ....^  c.|#4|..
ff 3d 99 34 91 2d 7d 0c 3b 48 4c 9d ce c6 9a d7  ÿ=4.-}.;HL...
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 790.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x316 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 790.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
10 00 00 00 28 02 00 00 28 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....(...(.......
Sorting index $I30 in file 790.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x5a8 is incorrect.
f0 ac 9b c8 30 a8 29 67 99 11 4e 18 10 c2 0c 5b  .¬.0¨)g.N....[
f7 f2 20 f4 ff 9a c8 b9 db 20 d3 54 66 53 cc 3d  .. .ÿ... .TfS.=
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1448.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x5a8 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1448.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 80 80 27 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ..'.....
76 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  va..............
Sorting index $I30 in file 1448.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x6fb is incorrect.
d4 7e 61 5c 5e bb 88 7f 58 1d 95 99 26 d8 60 ec  .~a\^..X.&.`ì
f6 87 3c 1c 4e 34 0e 5b d6 d8 ab 30 08 e1 0c 20  .<.N4.[..«0.á. 

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1787.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x6fb is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1787.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 80 80 27 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ..'.....
76 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  va..............
Sorting index $I30 in file 1787.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x782 is incorrect.
89 b8 ac 93 00 2e 57 5b f6 18 04 8c a9 18 ad c0  .¬..W[...©.­.
b6 ef 04 93 74 c0 39 c7 31 ee d5 66 38 1b 0d 7d  .ï.t.9.1î.f8..}
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1922.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x782 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1922.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 80 80 27 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ..'.....
76 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  va..............
Sorting index $I30 in file 1922.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x784 is incorrect.
60 7f d1 c3 cd 1b 17 1d 0d 3a b6 a5 e6 e9 0b 4b  `........:.¥æé.K
78 00 23 09 4c 74 f4 6c 15 7c 83 d2 e0 b7 eb c6  x.#    Lt.l.|.à.ë.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1924.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x784 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 1924.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 80 80 27 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ..'.....
76 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  va..............
Sorting index $I30 in file 1924.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0xfef is incorrect.
1a f1 a7 71 5c a1 54 43 a5 af d7 cb 14 9e 40 ea  ..§q\¡TC¥¯...@ê
43 e1 bf d2 a2 38 a0 74 13 5f b9 06 27 63 9b 90  Cá..¢8 t._..'c.

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4079.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0xfef is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4079.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fc 73 ac 41 be 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿüs¬A.=..
00 7c 14 2e b9 3e cf 01 39 8a 53 df 94 41 d1 01  .|...>..9S.A..
Sorting index $I30 in file 4079.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x1011 is incorrect.
a5 82 11 34 e7 74 ee 82 71 53 7d d8 69 30 a1 26  ¥.4çtîqS}.i0¡&
ad f9 0c e9 ec e4 23 86 5d 9f ef b2 65 99 94 e9  ­..éìä#.]ï.eé
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4113.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x1011 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4113.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fc 73 ac 41 be 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿüs¬A.=..
00 7c 14 2e b9 3e cf 01 39 8a 53 df 94 41 d1 01  .|...>..9S.A..
Sorting index $I30 in file 4113.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x1016 is incorrect.
49 43 0d ef 21 ad 18 d9 08 29 76 20 ac cb b0 14  IC.ï!­...)v ¬...
fb 1e 03 ce 23 fb ea aa 0e 3e 1d 9e b8 79 3c cd  ....#.êª.>..y<.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4118.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x1016 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 4118.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fc 73 ac 41 be 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿüs¬A.=..
00 7c 14 2e b9 3e cf 01 39 8a 53 df 94 41 d1 01  .|...>..9S.A..
Sorting index $I30 in file 4118.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x62e6 is incorrect.
a1 92 d5 e4 dd 59 74 e4 2e 38 d5 ea 34 b2 04 89  ¡..ä.Ytä.8.ê4..
aa da c2 72 d6 9c 31 22 53 48 55 3d 74 a6 99 c7  ª..r.1"SHU=t¦.

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 25318.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x62e6 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 25318.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ce fc 09 a5 0d 43 d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ.ü ¥.C..
00 66 bc eb b3 49 cf 01 79 01 fc a5 0d 43 d1 01  .f.ë.I..y.ü¥.C..
Sorting index $I30 in file 25318.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x763a is incorrect.
59 0e 14 e1 45 bb 5a 76 cd ad 0b 5a cc ba 1a 85  Y..áE.Zv.­.Z...
11 03 20 39 d1 2f b8 7b 0f a2 94 d6 e0 1a f5 c4  .. 9./.{.¢.à...

Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30266.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x763a is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30266.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 62 31 86 32 d1 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿb1.2.=..
81 fa 96 32 d1 3d d1 01 81 fa 96 32 d1 3d d1 01  .ú2.=...ú2.=..
Sorting index $I30 in file 30266.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x7643 is incorrect.
b7 c7 fd d7 93 9f 45 40 1c 53 3b 65 53 d3 8f e9  ..ý.E@.S;eS..é
74 08 b8 b7 08 e6 47 6c 8b 34 93 fe 7c 18 74 d3  t....æGl4.|.t.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30275.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x7643 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30275.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 62 31 86 32 d1 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿb1.2.=..
81 fa 96 32 d1 3d d1 01 81 fa 96 32 d1 3d d1 01  .ú2.=...ú2.=..
Sorting index $I30 in file 30275.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x7658 is incorrect.
38 dc cb 32 33 b7 dd bd 7d ca ea 95 2e 87 f9 e7  8..23...}.ê..ç
4a fc 73 9c 24 94 42 f2 ee f4 44 58 82 62 97 c6  Jüs$B.î.DXb.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30296.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x7658 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30296.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 58 72 e3 45 d1 3d d1 01  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿXrãE.=..
86 a7 ef 45 d1 3d d1 01 86 a7 ef 45 d1 3d d1 01  .§ïE.=...§ïE.=..
Sorting index $I30 in file 30296.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x765c is incorrect.
f9 cc 03 c1 80 95 33 09 37 63 7c 9c e8 8e 68 57  .....3 7c|è.hW
ea b8 7d d8 fa a5 3e 02 4e f8 73 6d 92 bf dc fa  ê.}.ú¥>.Nøsm...ú
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30300.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x765c is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30300.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Sorting index $I30 in file 30300.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x7667 is incorrect.
76 1f 1c f8 cc af 0b a3 f6 e1 48 da 77 14 84 1b  v..ø.¯.£.áH.w...
b1 ee 38 37 eb c9 19 c3 b2 99 da bf 9f 29 b1 e5  .î87ë......).å
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30311.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x7667 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30311.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Sorting index $I30 in file 30311.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x0 of index $I30
in file 0x7670 is incorrect.
e9 20 51 9d aa 7a 01 c5 9c cb 8f 01 db e9 d5 6e  é Qªz......é.n
b5 26 5d 9c c1 dd 51 22 f8 51 4b f5 bb 27 e5 f0  .&]..Q"øQK..'å.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30320.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x7670 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30320.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 0
```

I'm using windows 7 64bit and i don't know what to do, also i don't want to lose my vi files!

Comment: Files were already corrupted.  There isn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: Ok, forget about the corrupted data, what about the hdd itself?, i just need to fix it in order to use it normally again!

Comment: Let chkdsk fix the problem, but if you have corrupt files, sounds like this new hdd isn't all that new

Comment: If you ran chkdsk with the /R attribute, it should have fixed the corruption.  If it was all soft corruption, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.  If there were a lot of platter defects, that isn't a good sign for the drive being reliable in the future.  Did you check the SMART stats?

Comment: @Ramhound it won't fix anything, i ran it several times and every time it try to fix the same problems but it can't, and what about the new hdd!, it has the system and some files and there is no problems related to it!

Comment: @fixer1234 i'll try your suggestion after i make a backup of my files, and hope it's just a soft corruption, and no i didn't check SMART stats yet, should i? and how to?

Comment: Use the program of your choice that oldies plays the SMART status of your hdd

Comment: Backup before your hard drive fails. Better safe than sorry.